Flutter: Item is added only when button is pressed twice or more (Riverpod Inventory management)
I have an app that has an inventory of Items and I followed very similar approach to delete, add, update items methods; but add button is only working when pressed twice. If I press it 4 times, same item is added thrice.
Widget that has the button (and some other textfields about item name, etc):
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentItemList = ref.watch(jsonInventoryServiceNotifierProvider);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text("Manually Add An Item"),
        ),
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              //TEXT FIELD HERE TO INPUT ITEM NAME
               ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      const SnackBar(content: Text('Item Added!')),
                    );
                    Item newItem = Item(
                      productName: productNameTextFieldController.text,
                      isActive: true,
                    );
                    await ref
                        .read(jsonInventoryServiceNotifierProvider.notifier)
                        .insertItem(newItem);
                    currentItemList.when(
                        data: (item) {
                          if(item.any((element) =>
                              element.productName.toLowerCase() ==
                              (newItem.productName.toLowerCase()))) {
                            print("OPEN DIALOG BOX TO SAY THIS PRODUCT WAS BOUGHT BEFORE");
                          }
                        },
                        error: (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {},
                        loading: () {});
                    setState(() {});
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ],

Add Item method inside StateNotifierProvider class:
Future<void> insertItem(Item item) async {
    final currentState = state;
    late var currentList;

    if (currentState is AsyncData<List<Item>>) {
      currentList = currentState.value;
      state = AsyncValue.data([...currentList, item]);
    } else if (currentState is AsyncLoading) {
    } else if (currentState is AsyncError) {
    }
    inventoryResult.results = currentList;
    final jsonmap = inventoryResult.toJson();
    storage.writeFile(jsonmap);
}

Clearly I am missing something here about state management and widget rebuilts, event handling here but I could not figure out and some recommendations from similar SOF questions did not solve.
Let me know any improvements or fixes about my code, thank you.

you mean that insertItem is not called every time the button is clicked? if not, does the code go to  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {  branch?

I printed to the terminal from both inside insertItem method, and also from inside the button, code goes into both of these places and prints, but for insertItem, only after once you click the button exactly one time. Then it starts to work perfectly fine, then if you go to another screen and come back same situation again. Hope this makes sense.

@pskink More correctly, snackbar works right from the start so must be going inside that if branch each time; but only after the second click it goes into insertItem.

ok, in another words: add print('onPressed') just after onPressed: () async { and print('in if') just after if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) { and print('in insertItem') in the first line of insertItem method, what do you see if you press the button two times?

exactly this: onPressed; in if; in insertItem; onPressed; in if; in insertItem; but the item is only added once when I go look at the inventory!

I see, I just put another print there as well: right after if (currentState is AsyncData<List>) inside insertItem; and it is being printed twice like everyone else..

so you need inventoryResult.results = state.value; and not inventoryResult.results = currentList;? btw what do you need that currentList for at all?

Ah that fixes it! Thank you so much for taking the time.

sure, your welcome

and dont forget to remove currentList from your code as it is not needed
